# read, edit and update document.xml inside word folder in word/zip file with phpword

Tags: xml, zip, phpword

Working with Symfony2.3.4, PHP5.6.3 and PHPWord0.12.1.

I am trying to fill a template depending on certain fields fetched from my database. One of the elements I am trying to edit are some checkboxes from this template.

I googled a lot about this but found no solution that could apply to my specific situation.

Basically what I need is to extract the **document.xml** file from the word folder inside the zip file the word.docx really is.

Then edit it by replacing the content of the tag  with the checkbox symbol(checked or not).

I have achieved this so far, the problem is when I try to add this updated **document.xml** back into the .zip, it just doesn't do anything, it does not update the contents of the first **document.xml** or anything at all.

Here it is so far:

```
$xml = \SimpleXMLElement($this->zipClass->getFromName(' word/document.xml'));
$checkbox = $xml->xpath("w:body/w:sdt/w:sdtContent/w:p/w:r");

while(list(, $node) = each($checkbox)){
$node->t = <symbol-checked>;  //here I add a new tag to the "tree" with the desired symbol as content
}

$xml->saveXML('templates/document.xml');
```

note: I put  because I can't find out how to write the checkbox symbol used in word docs.

Well, so far it works, the part I can't get to work is updating the zip file with the new contents of **document.xml**

I thought it should be something like:

```
$this->zipClass->addFile('templates/document.xml', 'word/document.xml');
```

but it's like i'm doing nothing

help appreciated